# Infinite Scroll on a loop?

Tags: loop, infinite-scroll

I have a home page with four different loops (different category's)

On one of the loops I want it to display five posts but also have the infinite scroll on it.

I have installed the infinite scroll plugin but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

Here is my code for the loop:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
         <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'gabfire' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" class="thumbnail"><?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID,'thumbnail') ); ?><img src="<?php echo $url ?>" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
         <h4><strong><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'gabfire' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong></h4>

        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

        <p>
           <i class="icon-user"></i> by <?php echo get_the_author(); ?> | <i class="icon-calendar"></i> <?php the_date(); ?> | <i class="icon-tags"></i> Cat: <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name;?></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not pastebin your code, post only the relevant parts in your question.

Comment: I cant seem to put the code in the post?

Comment: Why can you not put code in the post?

Comment: It only posts a small amount of it, the full loop is in the paste bin.

Comment: You are not formatting the code correctly. I post code here all the time. It does work. Look for the `{}` button above the editor. Highlight your code and then click that button. Your question should not depend on a third party site.

Comment: nope cant get my code to show it breaks

Comment: Is a link to the site OK?

Comment: No. A link to the site is not ok. Post your code and put @s_ha_dum in a comment. I will fix the code formatting for you.

Comment: All done @s_ha_dum now you can see code.

Comment: @s_ha_dum any ideas?